# What's the difference between global memory and texture in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

What's the difference between global memory and texture in CUDA?
To speed up memory copying from host to device, which one is better?
I am going to use them for Image Processing.
I've seen the sample for bilateral filtering.
It used texture instead of global memory.

I'd like some to explain about it.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant "bilinear" interpolation, not "bilateral"?

Comment: @njuffa: There are both bilinear filter and bilateral filter. Bilinear filter use Bilinear interpolation and bilateral filter is a non-linear filter.

Comment: Bilateral Filter is a filter that removes noises from an Image.
It is widely used Filter but time consuming algorithm.
But I can see some CUDA samples including Bilateral Filter.
What I want to know is the benefit of using Texture instead of global Memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture memory is referred to a hardware unit that maps onto global memory. 
 Performing copy between host memory and GPU memory is always done with global memory involved it does not matter if a texture unit is mapped onto that piece of global memory or not. 
 
 You can read more about texture memory in [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#texture-memory) 
 
Bilateral filtering Sample uses texture unit to increase memory throughput by utilizing Texture unit caching mechanism.

Benefits of using texture memory:

- Enables caching of global memory
- Capability of caching data to maximize 2D spacial locality
- Linear interpolation in hardware
- Handling out-of-bounds addresses in hardware

Comment: Could you please tell the benefit of using Texture instead of using global memory?

Comment: I have added benefits of using texture memory. Understand that each feature of texture unit can be solved in software (kernel) with global memory only.